# Router won't connect to specific website

Tags: router

I have a Zyxel Armor Z2 router and have tried everything I can think of, even doing a factory reset, and no matter what I do I can't get it to access a specific website (my dad's website, brendans-island.com). I have determined it is the router because by plugging directly into the cable modem I am able to access the site. Ping reports no packets being lost and the output of tracert is as follows:

https://pastebin.com/9SNTQa6n

When I try to access it in a webbrowser, I get a timed-out error. Family finances being what they are I really don't want to buy a new router, but before doing the factory reset I disabled and tweaked just about everything I could think of and nothing seemed to work. Interesting to mention, though, that occasionally it does work, but that seems to be the exception. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any species of ad blocker installed in your browser?

Comment: try to do a dns lookup, idk maybe ull find something; could be that the router gives u some weird address for that
have u tried accessing the website through its ip-address?

Comment: I have tried it on three different devices (my dad's desktop, my laptop, and my phone), all with the same effect (two of which do not have ad blockers installed). I have tried using Google DNS and automatically acquiring my ISP's DNS server, both with the same effect. 

I don't know how to do a DNS lookup, but using the IP address from the ping and tracert commands I can confirm my webbrowser can't connect to the IP address either.

Comment: have you tried calling the router manufacturer, Zyxel? Also sometimes there's a setting for MTU size.. and if that's wrong it can affect some websites and not others. So you could try changing that. It might have different values like 1492 or 1500

Comment: when you connect it directly , without router, you say you can access the site, so why then try pinging?   Try pinging for when you can't access the site so for when the router is connected.

Answer (score 1):

Found what was wrong! The router had an MTU setting, and apparently it was slightly too large. I used the instructions here to find the proper value to set it to:

https://kb.netgear.com/19863/Ping-Test-to-determine-Optimal-MTU-Size-on-Router

In case the link goes dead, I will try to summarize it. Open CMD and type the following:

ping www.yahoo.com -f -l 1492

If you get messages saying "Packet needs to be fragmented but DF set", then type the same command in again, this time lowering the number by 10. Do this until you don't get the messages anymore, at which point you will want to increment up by 1 until you start getting the message again. Finally, take the highest number that worked and enter that number as your router's MTU size (for my router that was under expert mode>WAN>Internet Connection>IP Address). In case it is helpful my MTU size is now 1472.

Huge thank-you to barlop for pointing me in the right direction (I hadn't noticed the MTU option before).

Comment: the old  "I can access one website and I can't access another" error! ;-)  I only saw the error once in my life.. Was MTU setting on the router.

Answer (score 0):

This means you need to check the Outbound traffic to the website on port 443 (https port) to this website. I don't know how is the configurations on your FW, but it should be Source "Any" destination " 50.63.216.1" Protocol Https/http/ssl or port 443, it depends on ur FW...... the other issues is for the dns times out, you need to check the dns server, when you type nslookup and hit enter then type "server" and hit enter again, the response will your dns server, check port 53 Udp/TCP from ur machine to that server bidirectional should be allowed,   in short your issues its with the firewall policies and not the routing nor DNS. I hope these tips helps you out

Answer (score -2):

Open CMD (Just type "CMD" in Run) and run the following command:

Ping brendans-island.com

If you get something seemlier to this:

50.63.216.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=54 time=231.473 ms

then your DNS is fin and your routing is fine.

if not, tell us whats the output of the ping and will go for next step.

btw, to do nslookup, simply in "CMD" type nslookup hit enter and then type "brendans-island.com " you should get 50.63.216.1.

if this is all good then in "CMD" also type

telnet 50.63.216.1 443

you should get the following:

Trying 50.63.216.1...
Connected to 50.63.216.1.
Escape character is '^]'.

if telnet is not a valid command in ur cmd then you have to install telnet client

From Control Panel, click on Programs.
Under Programs and Features, click on Turn Windows Features on or off.
From the Windows Features window, using the slider, scroll down till you reach Telnet Client, select the check box beside it, then click on OK.

Comment: Ping finishes just fine. nslookup does give me the correct IP address, but interestingly it then proceeds to give me a "DNS Request Timed out" error twice before returning control of the CMD window to me. Using the telnet command on you gave on my desktop results in "could not open connection to the host, on port 443: Connect failed". EDIT: The nslookup command gives the same error even if I have my computer set to Google's DNS server.

Comment: in short your issues its with the firewall policies and not the routing nor DNS. Allow ports/ protocols 443/https/ssl source "any" destination " Yoourwebsite". also check port 53 udp/tcp bidirectional to ur DNS